# Gremlin-Python find all nodes connected by edges

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlinpython

I have a list of node labels as `node_labels`, where some of these may exist in a graph.

```
node_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Using this I can get the node labels or associated attributes.

```
g.V().has_label(*node_labels).to_list()
```

How can I modify the query so that I get only those node(s) where an edge exists (either incoming or outgoing) between the nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, said another way, you want any vertex with those labels if that vertex connects to another vertex with one those labels:

```
g.V().has_label(*node_labels).
  filter(both().has_label(*node_labels))
```

Here's a working example:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person')
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').where(both().hasLabel('person'))
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
```